# fputcsv putting quotes around line breaks

Tags: php, fputcsv

I used fputcsv to make CSV files for import by an outside service provider, I ran into issues where PHP does not use the correct line break characters if you leave it to default, it uses /n only instead of /r/n and I can't find a way to change this. I resolved this by using PHP_EOL at end of line to force the needed line break and thought everything was working. turns out it is putting double quotes around the /r/n line break and then putting /n in after it...

Here is the code:

```
            $csv[$i]['Station ID']=$station_ID;
            $csv[$i]['Program Start Date']=$date;
            $csv[$i]['Program Start Time']=$start_time;
            $csv[$i]['Program End Time']=$end_time;
            $csv[$i]['Duration']=$dur;
            $csv[$i]['Program Title']=$program;
            $csv[$i]['Program Description (optional)']=$desc;
            $csv[$i]['Category']=$genre;
            $csv[$i]['Sub Category']=$subgenre;
            $csv[$i]['Time Zone?']=$timezone;
            $csv[$i][]=PHP_EOL;

        }
        $prev_program = $program ;
        unset($gendesc, $desc, $dur, $gendur, $end, $end_time, $start, $start_time, $end_time);
        $i++;
    }


// create a file pointer connected to the output stream
$output = fopen("php://output",'w') or die("Can't open php://output");

// output headers so that the file is downloaded rather than displayed
header('Content-Type: text/csv; charset=utf-8');
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='" . $filename . "'");

// output the column headings
fputcsv($output, array('Station ID', 'Program Start Date', 'Program Start Time', 'Program End Time', 'Duration', 'Program Title', 'Program Description (optional)', 'Category', 'Sub Category', 'Time Zone?',PHP_EOL));

// loop over the rows, outputting them
foreach ($csv as $line) {
    $line = preg_replace('/(^|;)"([^"]+)";/','$1$2;',$line);
                fputcsv($output, $line);
}

fclose($output) or die("Can't close php://output");
}
?>
```

and here is the first 2 lines of output:

```
"Station ID","Program Start Date","Program Start Time","Program End Time",Duration,"Program Title","Program Description (optional)",Category,"Sub Category","Time Zone?","
"
36170,03/27/17,00:00,00:30,30,"Love Food","Love Food.",Other,Food,Atlantic,"
"
```

if I pull the PHP_EOL it outputs in a blob of text according to notepad (I have to have this legible so that users can verify/modify as necessary before send) but it seems to be correct in a code editor. Is there any way to change the default EOL statement from /n to /r/n in fputcsv? only reference to this I can locate is a description of a patch from 2008, except all that does is change it to the system default and this runs on a linux system where the default is /n.

Comment: *"from /n to /r/n"* - Just a sidenote: If you plan on doing that, the correct syntax is `\n` and `\r\n`.

Comment: those linefeeds only appear as new lines in the written file. You may have opened that file in the editor under another encoding method. If you want to output them to screen as new lines, user `nl2br()` or `<br>`'s.

Comment: and `PHP_EOL` is cross-platform, however I have seen in a few rare cases where someone had to use either `\n` or `\r\n` depending on their platform.

Comment: Have a look at this post of a guy solving the same issue: http://php.net/manual/en/function.fputcsv.php#90883

Comment: This is writing out to file to be sent to our provider. I am waiting to hear back if things work with just \n on their end (I messed up my slashes thanks for pointing that out.) I may need to tell my staff that they need up edit in excel instead of note from now on if it works since that loads it fine with EOL removed.